# Django ORM Filter By Checking Both column contains same values

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I have a model contains 3 column as follows:

```
Id NoOfL2 Open Delete Inprogress
1    2      1     1      0
2    4      1     2      1
3    3      3     0      0
```

I want to fetch all rows contains `NoOfL2 == Open`.

How should I found it using `Django ORM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions):

```
Foo.objects.filter(NoOfL2=F('Open'))
```

Comment: is `F('Open')` taking the sum of all the values in column 'Open' or looking for the same row of column 'Open'?

Comment: Same row column, but you could make some sum and use it in an F expression too.